# RTC: Jenkins checks out component as its sub dirs instead of one whole directory

Tags: jenkins, rational-team-concert

The component used to be checked out by Jenkins as a whole dir. Don't know why it starts to check it out as separate subdirs.

For example:

it should've checked out the componnet as:

`/com` (it has sub dirs like `/src`, `/include`, etc)

instead, it checks it out as:

```
/src
/include
/doc
...
```

And this only happens to this component, not seen on other components.

EDIT:

1. The log screenshot: (as you can see, the `/include`, `/doc` are checked out seperately)
   [image]
2. The configuration of Jenkins:
   [image]

Comment: Could you provide more information how you configured the checkout? It sounds like a configuration issue. Maybe you configured it in a way that tells Jenkins that you want to have the content of a directory and not the parent directory itself. Like that: 'repo/com/' -> content without parent, 'repo/com' -> parent and its content.

Comment: @ThomasHerzog I don't think that's the cause. We have no control to that kind of detail, all we did was just pick this component in a dialog window and hit "OK" button.

Comment: could you provide the config of jenkins, where you define the checkout? Is it SVN or GIT?

Comment: @ThomasHerzog We define the checkout in "Build definition" in RTC, more specifically, in the workspace of "build Definition". We use SCM as version control for RTC

Comment: I mean, shouldn't Jenkins's problem, right? why do other components get checked out properly?

Comment: I am not really familiar with RTC on Jenkins, but is there something different with this problematic component compared to the other components? When you look at the workspace are only the subdirs checked out, or is the execution just done within the component and your are mislead? When the other components work, then it sounds like the problematic component differs from the others somehow.

Comment: That's where I feel confused, too. Only the subdirs got checked out and this component is the same with others, no specific config for it.

Comment: Could you provide logs and the job configuration?

Comment: How do I share it?

Comment: Add it as images for instance

Comment: @ThomasHerzog Added

Comment: The logs and config does not tell much. Did you try to create a new job to check if occurrs there as well? Don't know how to help any further

Comment: That might be a good idea. Let me try

Comment: @ThomasHerzog The config and logs seem very normal. And just let you know that I tried creating a new jenkins job and it doesn't work, same issue.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you any further. Report an issue at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/projects/JENKINS/issues/JENKINS-54126?filter=allopenissues maybe those guys can help you, if no one else at stackoverflow can help you